# Error in Query (1066) - MySQL

Tags: mysql, moodle

I'm having a bit of a problem when I execute this query under MySQL 5.5.3. It returns **Error in Query (1066): Not unique table/alias: 'categories'**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lra.userid) AS learners, COUNT(DISTINCT tra.userid) AS teachers
FROM mdl_course AS courses, mdl_course_categories AS categories
LEFT JOIN mdl_context AS ctx ON c.id = ctx.instanceid
JOIN mdl_role_assignments  AS lra ON lra.contextid = ctx.id
JOIN mdl_role_assignments  AS tra ON tra.contextid = ctx.id
JOIN mdl_course_categories AS categories ON courses.category = categories.id
WHERE courses.category = categories.id
AND (
    categories.path LIKE '%/9/%' 
    OR categories.path LIKE '%/9'
    )
AND lra.roleid=5
AND tra.roleid=3
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as i have aliased the columns as well as the table names. Can anyone spot where I might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a select statement as

```
FROM mdl_course AS courses, mdl_course_categories AS categories
```

then

```
JOIN mdl_course_categories AS categories ON courses.category = categories.id
```

This makes it non unique alias

You should remove the select part and should be as

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lra.userid) AS learners, COUNT(DISTINCT tra.userid) AS teachers
FROM mdl_course AS courses
LEFT JOIN mdl_context AS ctx ON c.id = ctx.instanceid
JOIN mdl_role_assignments  AS lra ON lra.contextid = ctx.id
JOIN mdl_role_assignments  AS tra ON tra.contextid = ctx.id
JOIN mdl_course_categories AS categories ON courses.category = categories.id
```

Comment: Great thanks! I knew it'd be something daft on my part! Will accept as soon as I'm allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In the second line of query tyou have use a table name and in line 6 you have used taht table again.
Such as

```
FROM mdl_course AS courses, mdl_course_categories AS categories
```

And

```
JOIN mdl_course_categories AS categories ON courses.category = categories.id
```